# Show the line that returned 'Mean of empty slice'

Tags: python, list, numpy, error-handling, printing

I have multiple instances in my code where I calculate the mean of lists. Therefore, I was looking for a way to show the line of code where the warning 'Mean of empty slice' occurred as any normal errors do.

The input is a normal list `[1,2,3]` or a numpy list
`np.array([1,2,3])`

So I want something like this:
`File "file_name.py", line <line_number> in <folder_number>`

So far, I could print the outputs of all calculations of mean like this:

```
test1 = np.mean([1,2,3])
print('test1',test1)
```

But, I think, it is too redundant for the case when there are many such calculations in the code.

Is there a way to change the configuration of the warning so that it returns this information?

Comment: for what input are you getting this error

Comment: to any numpy and ordinary python lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.seterr(all='raise')` to escalate all numpy warnings to errors.

That way, your code will throw an exception and interrupt when there is a mean of empty slice and you will be able to see where it happened:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.seterr(all="raise")
{'divide': 'warn', 'over': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore', 'invalid': 'warn'}
>>> np.mean([]) # raises FloatingPointError
```